# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jta

I have a JTA transcation which manages transaction of 2 databases A and B.Now inside jta transcation i have a method that  return a entity from db A.How i want to set some different values to some primary key (primary key is composit primary key) and then persist the entity as a new record.But am getting following exception:

```
                                 <openjpa-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:778978M-OPENJPA-975 nonfatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Attempt to persist detached object "xyz.abc@616f991c".  If this is a new instance, make sure any version and/or auto-generated primary key fields are null/default when persisting.
FailedObject: xyz.abc-
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2421)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1021)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:645)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAExEmInvocation.persist(JPAExEmInvocation.java:339)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:133)
    at com.ibm.cloud.bss.db.data.controller.CostrateManager.createCostrate(CostrateManager.java:94)
    at com.ibm.cloud.bss.omt.catalog.impl.BundleManager.saveSubcomponentInECW(BundleManager.java:409)
    at com.ibm.cloud.bss.omt.catalog.impl.BundleManager.createBundle(BundleManager.java:274)
    at com.ibm.cloud.omt.OfferingManagementSOAPBindingImpl.createBundle(OfferingManagementSOAPBindingImpl.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:159)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1389)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
```

I searched on net and i fold this post similar to myne:
http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/persisting-an-entity-and-JPA-behaviour-with-referenced-entities-td210469.html

Answer (score 1):

From JPA 1.0 Spec:

> A new entity instance becomes both managed and persistent by invoking the persist method on it or by cascading the persist operation.
>   The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> If X is a detached object, the **EntityExistsException** may be thrown when the persist
>   operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException
>   may be thrown at flush or commit time.

If what you want is just change the primary key and the entity is a managed entity then just change its values and once the transaction is over those values will be persisted automatically. Another way is to change the values and call explicitly **merge** method.

But if what you want is to create a new object with the same properties of the retrieved object and keep the object retrieved intact you will have to first retrieve the object then create a new object and copy the properties from retrieved object to the new object and after that call the **persist** method on the new object. You can use **BeanUtils.copyProperties** method to copy the properties from a source object to a destination object or you can do it by your self.