# Smaller stacktrace: database exceptions

Tags: java, database, exception, openjpa

simple example, i have a user with a unique name in the database. Now i add a user with same name as an existing user. I get a very big exception- stacktrace for it. Can i reduce this output with a parameter from openjpa? I tried some of this, but nothing works: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/ref_guide_logging.html

The other solution is to check the name before persisting, but i think thats an overhead or?

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {

@EJB
private MyStateless stateless;

public void save(ActionEvent event){
    try{
    stateless.save();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("####EXCEPTIOn");
    }
}
}
```

---

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyStateless{
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
private EntityManager em;

public void save() {
    Person p = new Person(1, "Name");
    em.persist(p);
}   
}
```

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: myejb.Person@1100245.......

2014-03-02T10:43:47.969+0100|Information: ####EXCEPTIOn

Here i get the javax.ejb.EJBException with the wrapped EntityExistsException

Comment: exception.getMessage() (or some other kind of message I forgot)

Comment: reducing stacktrace size is something affecting the logs, "The other solution is to check the name before persisting" is affecting the code? Are you coding something using stacktraces???

Comment: I catch these exceptions and translate it in a own excpetion for user information via internationalisations etc.. And when i look at the log there are much overhead with big "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException" stackstraces. @DjDexter5GHz: I cant catch these exceptions before they print this big stacktrace. I get it in the try{}catch{} after it. Its only an idea, i can live without it, but when there is a solution i want to use it ;)

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz I add some code with exception output to explain it

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614812/org-apache-openjpa-persistence-entityexistsexception-in-jpa

Comment: I know what it is ;) that was only an example that i cant avoid THIS stacktrace in try / catch with .getMessage() :)